# Nested categories in Autocomplete - reset/clear after selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm building a UI for filtering products by category using a "nested" autocomplete component.

I have a breadcrumb to show the currently selected categories and autocomplete to select a category in the current level.

The categories are represented by a tree of different depths (can be up to 20), for example:

```
Women > Accessories > Glasses
Women > Underwear
Men > Shoes > Sandals
```

In the examples above there are 3 category levels (but it can be more than that).

First, the user can choose from options `[Women, Men]`. Then, he can choose an option from the 2nd level of the selected option. If the user chose `Women` he can now choose between `[Accessories, Underwear]`. The breadcrumb will updated accordingly.

My problem is that the selected option stays after the selection, while I'm changing the options list behind the scenes. That yields the following warning (which I want to get rid of):

```
 MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with `"Women"`.You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

In addition, the "last" selected option stays in the textbox and I want it to be empty for a new selection (of a differ category level). How do I do that?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/autocomplete-pqjnj5?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00063b6hner787kv%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B71.57657657657657%252C28.42342342342343%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00023b6hwqxq1jsy%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00033b6h74ztngiz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00053b6hyfkvuo3n%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltvmeprr00023b6hwqxq1jsy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00023b6hwqxq1jsy%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522cltvmeprr00053b6hyfkvuo3n%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00043b6hs2jk29j6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00053b6hyfkvuo3n%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00043b6hs2jk29j6%2522%257D%252C%2522cltvmeprr00033b6h74ztngiz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvmeprr00033b6h74ztngiz%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A17.835648148148152%257D) is a code sandbox that shows my use-case.

```
type CategoryLevel = {
  [key: string]: CategoryLevel;
};

function getCurrentCategoriesList(
  categoriesTree: CategoryLevel,
  categories: string[]
) {
  let subTree = categoriesTree;
  for (const category of categories) {
    subTree = subTree[category] || {};
  }

  if (!subTree) {
    return [];
  }
  return Object.keys(subTree);
}

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newOptions = getCurrentCategoriesList(categoriesTree, categories);
    setOptions(newOptions);
  }, [categories]);

  function handleCategoryChange(_event, newValue: string | null) {
    if (newValue != null) {
      setCategories([...categories, newValue]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box className="App">
      <h1>Hello Categories</h1>
      <h2>
        <Button onClick={() => setCategories([])}>Reset</Button>
        {categories.join(" > ")}
      </h2>

      <FormControl>
        <Autocomplete
          disableClearable
          open={open}
          sx={{ width: 300 }}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpen(false);
          }}
          onOpen={() => {
            setOpen(true);
          }}
          noOptionsText="No Categories"
          options={options}
          onChange={handleCategoryChange}
          // onInputChange={handleInputChange}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={
                getCurrentCategoriesList(categoriesTree, categories).length > 0
                  ? "Category"
                  : "NA"
              }
              variant="standard"
            />
          )}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}


categoriesTree = {
  Men: {
    "T-Shirts": {
      Polos: {},
    },
    Shorts: {},
    Jackets: {},
    Accessories: {
      Glasses: {},
      Belts: {},
      Underwear: {},
      Socks: {},
    },
  },
  Women: {
    "T-Shirts": {
      Polos: {},
    },
    Shorts: {},
    Jackets: {},
    Accessories: {
      Glasses: {},
      Belts: {},
      Underwear: {},
      Socks: {},
    },
  },
};
```